# Is every frame homomorphism induced by a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure

Let $M$ be the Lebesgue measure algebra of the unit interval $[0,1]$, i.e. equivalence classes of Lebesgue measurable sets modulo sets of measure $0$. This is a complete Boolean algebra, hence in particular a frame.
Let $\Omega(\mathbb{R})$ be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. $\Omega(\mathbb{R})$ is also a frame. A frame homomorphism is a function between frames preserving arbitrary sups and finite meets (in particular, $\bot$ and $\top$).

Any measurable function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ induces a frame homomorphism $\Omega(\mathbb{R}) \to M$ by taking (equivalence classes of) preimages.

My question is, does every frame homomorphism $F : \Omega(\mathbb{R}) \to M$ arise from a measurable map $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why is $M$ complete? It is only $\sigma$-complete, as far as I know.

Comment: The measure algebra $M$ is complete because it satisfies the countable chain condition, i.e. all strictly increasing chains are countable. The proof can be found, e.g. in Halmos' Boolean Algebras.

Comment: Note that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is not complete (otherwise every set would be Lebesgue measurable). But passing to equivalence classes, we get completeness.